# Are Pokemon farmed and eaten?

Tags: pokemon

Meat seems common in Pokemon. Does meat come only from real-world animals or are Pokemon also hunted and farmed for meat? In the real world, some animals are designated as pets and eating them is criticized. Is there a "pets and food" ethical distinction in the Pokemon world, which draws the line at eating Pokemon, or designates certain Pokemon as food?

I would love answers that find widespread present-day Pokephagy. The Pokedex says Farfetch'd had been hunted to near-extinction, so it does not indicate present-day Pokephagy. The Pokedex also says Basculin are delicious, but not information about whether its a choice for a normal seafood lover.

Comment: Similar question on Anime: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/836/7579

Comment: When Iron Chef was a Japanese import (not an English reboot) there were jokes about Iron Chef / pokemon (that is, being the featured ingredient) and remarks about pikichu sushi.  Non-canon, of course!  But you know it happens.

Comment: Pokemon is basically cock fighting. If 10 year old kids pit pokemon against each other in the ring until one looses consciousness, why would they have any compunction against eating them?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This article at Modern Farmer, ["The Food Politics of Pokémon"](http://modernfarmer.com/2014/05/food-politics-pokemon/), is actually pretty in-depth and covers both the games and the anime. (See also [this Bulbapedia article](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_food#Humans_eating_Pok.C3.A9mon).)

Miltank is farmed for its milk in the anime. It's never stated outright whether their meat is also used; although hamburgers are eaten on the show, non-Pokémon cows are [implied to exist in the show's universe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJuO9.png) (and [other animals do exist](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Animals_in_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world)).

Other Pokémon are eaten, though they are not farmed.

In the games, the black-market delicacy "SlowpokeTail", the tail of a Slowpoke, is sold by the evil Team Rocket. Presumably Slowpokes are poached for their tails, not farmed.

In the anime, the Pokédex says that Farfetch'd is nearly extinct because it has been over-hunted for food. It's not clear whether this is poaching or legal hunting.

In the games you can also read a [Sinnoh Folk Tale](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sinnoh_myths#Sinnoh_Folk_Tales) that say that people catch/caught Pokémon in the sea or stream and ate them. It also says that when the bones are thrown back into the sea, they'll regenerate. The last part is probably a folk tale, but the fishing and eating of Pokémon might be true.

According to the games' Pokédex, the Pokémon Basculin is "remarkably tasty", insinuating that they're eaten by humans. (Thanks, DisturbedNeo.)

Comment: Apparently Basculin are "remarkably tasty", according to X and Omega Ruby's Pokedex entries, and according to the anime, Magikarp are all "fins and scales" and don't provide much in the way of nutrition.

Comment: Is there any Pokemon-eating that is not ethically questionable and fringe? I was hoping that they reveal where the burgers come from since that shows their ethics.

Comment: @aitchnyu Perhaps Basculin, as mentioned by DisturbedNeo, but it's vague. Sinnoh Folk Tales (mentioned in the Bulbapedia) say that Pokémon caught from the sea are eaten and that when the bones are thrown back into the sea the Pokémon regenerate – that sounds like a folk tale indeed, but the fishing part might be true. I'll add them to my answer.

Comment: @CreationEdge - As I remember it, Brock or James _tries_ to eat it, but its scales are too thick to break, so James kicks it into the sea, where it becomes a Gyarados.

Comment: I remember watching an episode **several** years ago where there were some fried Magikarps at a fair or something, but I cannot remember the episode. I'm pretty sure it was either in the Kanto series or the Johto one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the restaurants in Pokemon X and Y serve some dishes explicitly made of Pokemon.

Comment: @tobiasvl You wrote Cherubi, but DisturbedNeo's comment mentions Basculin.

Comment: @AustinBurk Thanks.

Comment: Man I wanna try a Medium cooked Miltank now

Answer (score 10):

In S1 E49* *So close, yet so Fafetch'd* we have a PokéDex entry that clearly indicates Pokemon are eaten:

> Farfetch'd, a wild duck Pokémon. Farfetch'd makes a delicious meal, especially when cooked with leek. Because of this, Fafetch'd is nearly extinct.

[image] [image] [image]

Early in the season, on E15 "Pokémon Shipwreck", we see the stranded group daydream about eating Magikarp, to the point that Meowth actually tries to eat one but breaks his teeth on Magikarp's armored scales.

[image] [image] [image] [image]
<sup>Filleted, fried, marinated! The only thing Magikarp is good for is a meal!</sup>

Much later in the anime, in the *Diamond and Pearl* series, E144 *An Egg Scramble!* shows people drinking MooMoo Milk and eating ice cream made from it. It's generally known that MooMoo Milk comes from Miltank:

[image] [image]

In the games, you get the milk on MooMoo Farm, and have to help heal their Miltank. In the manga, *Miltank Melee*, MooMoo Farm is also featured, and also includes a sick Miltank that starts producing milk again once healed. The key word here is ***farm***.

There's also ranches, such as Laramie Ranch, but the show doesn't indicate that any of the cattle-type Pokémon there are *eaten*, instead their raised to be stronger for trainer battles.

As I was looking into this details (some of which are pretty fresh to me, as I'm rewatching the series with my oldest child), I found that several of these cases are covered in this Bulbapedia article's section ["Human's eating Pokémon"](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_food#Humans_eating_Pok.C3.A9mon) and "Food produced by Pokémon".

However, most of the concepts of Pokémon being food go away as the games, anime and manga go on. Those early episodes also included other oddities, such as a variety of giant Pokémon (in several episodes), and references to real-world locations (such as Melvin the magician that wants to perform in Las Vegas) and historical figures that are generally phased out.

<sup>*Some numbers are different than those listed on sites like Bulbapedia, I'm using the numbering used by Netflix, which is where I'm actually watching the show.</sup>

Comment: It's so very creepy that Fafetch'd is delicious when cooked with a leak and he actually carries one around with him. Plus eating Pokemon in and of itlsef is horrific, **they can talk**.

Comment: @Daft What are they gonna do? **Talk** you out of eating them?

Comment: @Aegon no, but they might **talk** to you while you're trying to kill and cook them. Pokemon can take a serious amount of damage, so killing them is gonna take a while.

Comment: @Aegon They could organize against humans, socializing works in their favour in this case.